# Sources tab in chrome dev tools is not displaying the right files

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

Im trying to debug and set breakpoints in my code, but whenever I navigate to the Sources tab, it displays files that are not the actual code, always formatted like:

```
import { render, staticRenderFns } from "./Index.vue?vue&type=template&id=e99f4d94&scoped=true&"
import script from "./Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&"
export * from "./Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&"


/* normalize component */
import normalizer from "!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js"
var component = normalizer(
  script,
  render,
  staticRenderFns,
  false,
  null,
  "e99f4d94",
  null
  
)

/* vuetify-loader */
import installComponents from "!../../../node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/runtime/installComponents.js"
import { VCol } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VGrid';
import { VRow } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VGrid';
installComponents(component, {VCol,VRow})


/* hot reload */
if (module.hot) {
  var api = require("D:\\vue-hot-reload-api\\dist\\index.js")
  api.install(require('vue'))
  if (api.compatible) {
    module.hot.accept()
    if (!api.isRecorded('e99f4d94')) {
      api.createRecord('e99f4d94', component.options)
    } else {
      api.reload('e99f4d94', component.options)
    }
    module.hot.accept("./Index.vue?vue&type=template&id=e99f4d94&scoped=true&", function () {
      api.rerender('e99f4d94', {
        render: render,
        staticRenderFns: staticRenderFns
      })
    })
  }
}
component.options.__file = "src/views/adas/Index.vue"
export default component.exports
```

No matter what I do, I cannot find the actual Vue files that I am trying to debug

I have tried setting a debugger in my Vue code, have tried clicking the link to the screen in the Console tab that redirects to the above code still, and tried searching for the file in dev tools and still directing me to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate sourcemap.

If you are using vue-cli, you can do it like this.

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  }
})
```

Comment: Trying this, I cant compile now: TypeError: defineConfig is not a function. Also I have had sourcemap activated this whole time, minus the transpileDependencies line.  I should add that the dev tools work fine on everybody elses machines except mine so its weird that it would be something i havent activated.